# Backbone Render View on model update

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm writing a sample app using backbone.js.

On update of my model I re-render my view in this fashion

```
$('.target').html("");
$('.target').append(this.$el.html(this.template(model)))
```

Once the view is re-rendered after model update [on change event], events attached to the `el`'s children gets lost [doesn't seem to be like `jQuery` live]. Is this a known issue or am I missing something? Should I try to replace html instead of `append`? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBjnj/)

Comment: You might want to fix your fiddle so that it runs. eg. using jQuery and including Underscore and Backbone as well

Comment: you don't need two statements. Just use one: `$('.target').html(this.$el.html(this.template(model)))`, which is equivalent to clearing the HTML and appending a new one

Comment: @Mike Fielden Then I might need to put my entire app :D  I thought the view would suffice to understand my issue

Comment: @Matanya you are right I hope it worked. Let me do a final testing and comeback. I was initially doing `$this.el.html()` which missed the wrapper div. But your soln fixed it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once the view is in DOM, you don't need to keep removing and appending it. I think the simplest way to manage this is to remove the DOM insertion from the view altogether, and let the caller of `view.render` to take care of it.

View:

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template(model));
  return this;
}
```

Caller (on first render):

```
var view = new SomeView();
$('.target').append(view.render().el);
```

On subsequent renders:

```
view.render();
```

After the view has been rendered into DOM it can keep happily re-rendering itself without having to know anything about parent views. The event bindings should also stay intact between renders.

Comment: But append would add the same content twice or as many times I keep updating my model rite coz of `append` instead of replace?

Comment: @Tamil the point is that you only `append` it once, when you want the view to be first shown. After that it's enough to call `render` on the view, because `view.$el` is already in DOM. I updated my answer for clarity. But yes, `$.replaceWith` or any other way would have the same result.

Comment: Note that if `this` view contains subviews, in your render function you will need to add `this.delegateEvents();`.